# How to check in MS Access in a Tabular form check data before and after updating on changes?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, tabular

I have a tabular form in MS Access 2010. I can do rowchanges. I want to check if in a row has changed fieldvalues. For example:

Row X has the following fields with the following values

```
Field1: Mickey Mouse
Field2: Donald Duck
Field3: Dagobert Duck
```

The users changes the Field2:

```
Field1: Mickey Mouse
Field2: X-Men
Field3: Dagobert Duck
```

How can I check if the value of field has changes from Donald Duck to X-Men?

Comment: When do you want to detect the change? Before it is committed to the database? After it is committed? As it's being typed into the field?

Comment: After it is committed to the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in just knowing 'something, somewhere' changed, you can use the Form 'AfterUpdate' event. However, that will not tell you the old value - it will only show the current value.

You can use the 'AfterUpdate' event for each control you want to monitor i.e.

```
Private Sub DateChanged_AfterUpdate()
    Debug.Print "Ctl After Update" & vbTab & Me.DateChanged.OldValue & vbTab & Me.DateChanged
End Sub
```

The 'BeforeUpdate' event also will show the '.Old' value.

If you need to track many fields, I have seen some people clone the record to memory than compare after the update.